# Alter table to add a check condition in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, alter-table, check-constraints

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE SHOW ( 
    ID VARCHAR2(10), 
    GENRE VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT CH_GENRE CHECK (GENRE IN ('war','western')), 
    )
```

How can I add 'drama' to ch_genre using an alter table?
I supposed that is something like:

```
ALTER TABLE TV_SHOW
ADD CONSTRAINT ADD_ROMANTIC
  CHECK (GENRE IN ('romantic'));
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you need to drop and recreate the constraint:

```
alter table show drop constraint ch_genre;
alter table show 
    add constraint ch_genre 
    check (genre in ('war', 'western', 'romantic'))
    enable
;
```

If you have a lot of rows, validating the constraint may be expensive. On the other hand, since we are just adding another possible value, we know that all values are valid already, so we can skip the validation as follows:

```
alter table show 
    add constraint ch_genre 
    check (genre in ('war', 'western', 'romantic'))
    enable novalidate
;
```

If you find yourself modifying the list of values on a regular basis, that's an indication that you should have a separate table to store that list, say `genres`, along with a foreign key that relates `show` to `genres` (probably through an integer, surrogate primary key rather than a string).

Answer (score 1):

Simply>>
Drop and Recreate Your Constraint

```
 ALTER TABLE SHOW Drop CONSTRAINT CH_GENRE; ALTER TABLE SHOW ADD
 CONSTRAINT CH_GENRE CHECK (GENRE IN ('war','western','Drama'));
```

Comment: your Table Contain Data?? I mean Column GENRE Contain Data Not in ('war','western','Drama') Those Values??

Answer (score 1):

Drop and recreate the check constraint like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SHOW ( 
    ID VARCHAR2(10), 
    GENRE VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT CH_GENRE CHECK (GENRE IN ('war','western'))
    );

Table SHOW created.

alter table SHOW drop constraint CH_GENRE ;

Table SHOW altered.

alter table SHOW add constraint CH_GENRE check (GENRE IN ('war','western','romantic'));

Table SHOW altered.
```